# Should I encrypt my cookies using AES?

Tags: server, encryption, cryptography, cookies

I'm going to encrypt the following data (server side):

`email, IP, username`

```
{
    *IP*: {
        email: *email at this IP*
        username: *username of email IP*
    } 
    *IP2*: {
        email: *email at this IP*
        username: *username of email IP*
    } 
}
```

I want to keep user name in cookie so I don't have to access database everytime I insert the username into the users page.

Is this a bad idea?

I don't care about them tampering with the cookie, because that will corrupt it and I can just reset it. Users will not be authorised if their IP doesn't match any of the accounts in their cookie, so that they're not logged out every time they log in, which happened with cPanel, as mentioned in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tso5rhzQYBc&t=1036s

Comment: "Bad idea" how? In what aspect? Are you asking about security? If yes, what is your threat model? IOW, what is it that you are securing, and what is it that you are securing against? How much money, resources, brains, and determination does your attacker have?

Comment: I've no knowledge of threat levels, but I want it to be impossible to fraudulantly appear logged in. I included the IP to prevent session hijacking.

Comment: Nothing is impossible given a determined enough attacker. It makes no sense to talk about security without a precisely specified, detailed, comprehensive threat model: *what* are you securing? *What attacks* are you securing it against? *Who* is your attacker? How much money are they willing to spend, what resources do they have, how much time do they have? *What* are they doing? Say, kidnapping your server admin's daughter and forcing him to simply download the database and send it to them? Break your lead developer's legs and force him to integrate a backdoor?

Comment: Im securing against people sending cookies I didnt create, so I can simply extract data about the user server side. I don't know my hacker, but I want a security level of something like facebook. How do they handle their cookies?

Comment: That's some very dark stuff, by the way.

Comment: If you're just looking for a way to save few database queries, I suggest you using a cache, and only putting random identifiers in cookies.

Comment: So you're saying store cookies plain text and then what? Check database if right IP?

Comment: A cookie is client-side data. You may have some control over them, but ultimately they are prone to tampering, even if you use HTTPS and set your cookie as HTTP-Only. You cannot be 100% sure you'll never receive any other cookie than the ones you sent, since the client decides which HTTP headers they'll send to you. That being said, **why** do you want to store these data in a cookie ? Are you trying to implement a Single Sign On scheme somehow ?

Comment: And to help you create a better question: Which protocol are you using, HTTP or HTTPS ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Theres no point in them sending me fake cookies... because the decryption will fail... HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: I've read the updated question, and I'm still in doubt. What are you trying to achieve ? When you say *"I want to keep user name in cookie so I don't have to access database everytime I insert the username into the users page."*, that isn't very clear to me what you're trying to do. Is it just for display purposes ? Or are you going to use it for authentication ? If it's for display purposes only, you can send it plaintext. No need to encrypt at all.

Comment: I'm using the email to authenticate user, and username to display it to user

Comment: @Tobi Decryption may not fail. I can take someone else's cookies and send them. If you aren't comparing the IP in the cookie to the IP of the connection, then I'm done. If you are then I can spoof their IP address too (and also your users may well have trouble with NATs and proxies). I won't get the response, but maybe I don't need it, or maybe I'm on a shared LAN and I can access the results.

Comment: HTTPS @DerekElkins

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing is the same spirit of a [JWT](https://jwt.io/). JWTs aren't encrypted, but they're signed so you can verify authenticity. Nobody can forge a JWT unless they've cracked your key. I would recommend using them instead of rolling your own because JWT are being used by many organizations for several years now.

JWT verification and signing libraries are available in most programming languages, and you can choose symmetric or asymmetric signing.

Comment: I dont want user to have any visibility of data

Comment: +1 For recommending that the user not go around trying to re-invent the wheel and end up creating yet another *insecure* solution in the process.

Comment: I just implemented my own sessions